# apply a function over a list of raster layers

Tags: r, raster, r-sf

I have a list of 34 RasterLayers like this:

```
[[34]]
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  10  bands)
dimensions : 6899, 9663, 66665037  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
extent     : -6.685352, -4.081226, 39.39795, 41.2572  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : D:/TFM/Imagenes/Imagenes_sinClip/2017.tif 
names      : X2017
```

I want to crop all the RasterLayers of the list using a `simple feature` like this:

```
> aoi
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -6.571744 ymin: 39.44875 xmax: -4.10362 ymax: 41.22031
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
  Id     area                       geometry
1  0 29488.98 POLYGON ((-6.122013 41.2203...
```

To do that, I used lapply:

```r
crop <- lapply(x = myrasterList, y = aoi, FUN = crop(x, y))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'crop': objeto 'x' no encontrado

Comment: I think you need `Map`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: you can do `Map(crop, myrasteList, aoi)`

Answer (score 1):

The FUN argument of `lapply` does not work like that when you add arguments to the function. You need to do something like

```
crop <- lapply(myrasterList, y = aoi, FUN = function(i) crop(i, y))
```